# How to add tooltip showing row details as table for DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net

In `ASP.NET`, a `DataGrid` shows other details from another table and a tooltip shows additional details from another table.

Any `JQuery` or `JavaScript` suggestions are welcome. I tried the following code so far:

```
if (e.Item.DataItem == null)
  return;
int documentID = int.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "documentid").ToString());
//  string documentName = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Document Name").ToString();
string FileType = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "FileType").ToString();
```

And I receive the following error:

> cannot implicitly conversystem.web.ui.webcontrols.table to string

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to re-read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Please attempt to rephrase your question to make it focus on the exact problem at hand and not everything you use in that application.